If one's luggage was inspected by the security, can one obtain the CCTV camera footage of the baggage inspection rooms showing the luggage inspection?
I read:

all baggage inspection rooms have CCTV cameras with heavy accountability, so there’s never a concern about theft.

This makes me wonder: if one's luggage was inspected, can one obtain the CCTV camera footage of the baggage inspection rooms showing the luggage inspection?

In what part of the world are you wanting CCTV footage?  For what reason are you wanting CCTV footage?

Never put anything in check in luggage that is worth stealing and you do not need to worry.

@Willeke Time for my PSA again?  Checked luggage: Never expect to see it again.  Hand luggage: Be able to drop it and run at any time. Items vital to your trip: Keep on your person.

To answer the title question in the linked article, the only time we had luggage wrapped it ended up with box cutter slashed all over. Just don’t.

I didn't read the article, so you may want to specify where they are speaking. I was thinking there is no CCTV camera on baggage inspections (and so I expect in Europe). On other handling parts: possibly, but IIRC Italy forbid them (although there were high rate of stolen things) to protect workers.

european-union (+ norway iceland luxembourg) and united-kingdom
Under Article 15, GDPR, you have the right to access any of your personal data from a data controller

The data subject shall have the right to obtain from the controller confirmation as to whether or not personal data concerning him or her are being processed, and, where that is the case, access to the personal data and the following information:

It is contentious when CCTV footage becomes personnal data, but Article 4

‘personal data’ means any information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person (‘data subject’); an identifiable natural person is one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, an identification number, location data, an online identifier or to one or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic, mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person;

If your face can be clearly seen, then it is for sure personal data and you can access it under Article 15

Conclusion, as you are not there when your luggage is searched you cannot get the footage.

@Willeke There should PII on the luggage tags such as your name.  But if it is human readable format (the bag tag page is an interesting read) I doubt it is readable by any CCTV from a distance.  However, I expect that the systems that track the bags themselves should be open for inspection under GDPR laws.  Bu that is not what the FOP asked about.

The GDPR has exceptions for government action, and also the need to balance the personal information of multiple parties. If the video shows the owner of the baggage and the officials and uninvolved third parties, it would seem far from clear that the video should be released.
